# Pixel 4XL detected in fastbootd but Pixel 6 not detected - fastboot detects Pixel 6 and adb worked w/ Pixel 6 BEFORE flashing attempt

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, fastboot, android-12, google-pixel-6

How can I get my Pixel 6 to be recognized in fastbootd??? My Pixel 4XL is detected in fastbootd.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I've tried multiple USB cables including USB to USB-c and USB-c to USB-c.
I've tried multiple versions of fastboot:

fastboot version 1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2

fastboot version 31.0.2-eng.apps.20220224.125224

fastboot version 32.0.0-8006631

The Pixel 4XL and Pixel 6 are both successfully recognized in fastboot (bootloader).
The Pixel 4XL and Pixel 6 were successfully recognized by adb (before flashing attempt on Pixel 6).
The Pixel 4XL is recognized by fastbootd, but the pixel 6 is not recognized in fastbootd:

```
Rebooting into fastboot                            OKAY [  0.000s]
< waiting for any device >
```

I can't get the Pixel 6 to boot up now because I was in the process of flashing after compiling image from https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers#source-code-tags-and-builds:

```
~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ fastboot flashall -w
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: slider-1.0-7753224
Baseband Version.....: g5123b-83783-210427-B-7318032
Serial Number........: xxxxxxxxxxx
--------------------------------------------
Checking 'product'                                 OKAY [  0.000s]
Setting current slot to 'b'                        OKAY [  0.006s]
Sending 'boot_b' (65536 KB)                        OKAY [  0.596s]
Writing 'boot_b'                                   OKAY [  0.079s]
Sending 'dtbo_b' (16384 KB)                        OKAY [  0.152s]
Writing 'dtbo_b'                                   OKAY [  0.021s]
Sending 'vbmeta_b' (4 KB)                          OKAY [  0.000s]
Writing 'vbmeta_b'                                 OKAY [  0.002s]
Sending 'vbmeta_system_b' (4 KB)                   OKAY [  0.000s]
Writing 'vbmeta_system_b'                          OKAY [  0.002s]
Sending 'vendor_boot_b' (65536 KB)                 OKAY [  0.608s]
Writing 'vendor_boot_b'                            OKAY [  0.076s]
Rebooting into fastboot                            OKAY [  0.000s]
< waiting for any device >
fastboot: error: Failed to boot into userspace fastboot; one or more components might be unbootable.
```

The device successfully enters fastbootd, but my linux box cannot detect it.

Comment: I can't get the phone to boot up now because I was flashing:

Comment: it did work fine

Comment: so fastbootd is working, only connection issue.. can you see any changes in `lsusb` when un+replugged?

Comment: "Your device is corrupt. It can't be trusted and may not work properly." after changing slots

Comment: Yes, I can see changes in lsusb when plugged/unplugged

Comment: I take that back... I can see changes in lsusb when plugged/unplugged when in fastboot bootloader, but I cannot see changes in lsusb when in fastboot fastbootd

Comment: you can flash super.img from fastboot instead